# Syntax error html

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, highcharts

Can anyone help me validate this code in Dreamweaver? It is the line "enabled: false !important;" that shows a syntax error. Can't spot why. Many thanks.

```
<body>
<wicket:panel>
<span wicket:id="notifier">
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
$('#container').highcharts({
credits: {
enabled: false !important;
    },
});
});
} // end ready
</script>
```

More: When I recode it like this...

```
credits: {
enabled: false !important;
},
```

The error moves to the first line - "credits: {"

Comment: The error is exactly correct; no such syntax exists.  Javascript is not CSS.

Comment: You mean it's just because it's java - there's nothng wrong with the code?

Comment: No; I mean your _JavaScript_ makes no sense.

Comment: ah - will check back with my java guy - thanks

Comment: Try to replace your entire `<script>...</script>` with the example I gave and this should fix your current syntax issue (although with so little information, I cannot guarantee that this will solve everything...)

Comment: Btw. I think you should do some research - Java and Javascript is not the same thing..

Comment: Java is to Javascript as car is to carpet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know anything about [Highcharts JS](http://www.highcharts.com/) (your issue is a syntax typo in the first place), but according to [this reference page](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#credits) and [this example](http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/jquery/1.7.2/highslide-software/highcharts.com/tree/master/samples/highcharts/credits/enabled-false/), I would try the following:

```
<script>
  $(document).ready(function(){
    $('#container').highcharts({
      credits: {
        enabled: false
      }
    });
  }); // end ready
</script>
```

In summary:

- As SLacks said, `!important` is a CSS instruction, and this is a JavaScript object.
- The following syntax is invalid: `{ foo: bar; }`, which is why I removed the semicolon `;`.
- You had an extra `}` that needed to be removed.